# Rotating every 3 bits of integer in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, performance, bit-manipulation

Note the following may have exactly the same solution if x is any positive integer, but for the exact problem at hand:

Choose an integer 0 < n < 11. Let x be an integer whose binary representation is given by pasting together up to n of the 3-bit strings: 001, 010, 100, 111 in some order (this is "Numbers with digits 1,2,4,7 when written in base 8", see e.g. http://oeis.org/A308496 ). Let y be the integer formed by rotating each 3-bit substring of x by 1 to the left. E.g. if 
(x)_2 = 001_010_111_100 then (y)_2 = 010_100_111_001

Problem: Let x_1, x_2, ... x_m be a sequence of such x for a given n, find the corresponding y_1, y_2, ... y_m.

If m is less than, say, a few thousand, then speed is not really an issue. One could e.g. break "001_010_111_100" down into an array [001, 010, 111, 100] and perform bit rotation for each element of the array.

However, once m becomes quite large (e.g. > 10^6), this task needs to be optimized as much as possible. Any suggestions (to a C++ beginner)?

Comment: Is this homework or any other school assignment?

Comment: What are your own thoughts on how to approach this?

Comment: No homework, I'm doing image processing- therefore millions of entries. I will spare everyone the details.

Comment: Build a conversion array of length 256 that converts one byte to another. Maybe an array of length 16, to convert nibbles, is even more efficient because of how various caches work. Maybe. Do a test.

Comment: For best performance maybe the solution lies in some assembler magic (MMX, SSE, FMA; I'm just throwing acronyms here without any knowledge in the technology).

Comment: @Dialecticus Thank you- I will try!

Comment: What is the original data type? If you have a thousand segments, it is surely no standard integer type. And what you work with is surely relevant to us.

Comment: @Aziuth e.g. just a standard 32bit unsigned int. Each integer x consists of a maximum of 10 3-bit strings, i.e. is less than 32bits. There are thousands of 32bit integers to process, not thousands of 3-bit segments which make up a single integer- that would be a very large integer :).

Answer (score 4):

A basic approach is to use the same logic as usual for a rotate, so:

Shift left

```
ABC_DEF_GHI in
BCD_EFG_HI0 out
```

Shift right

```
ABC_DEF_GHI in
00A_BCD_EFG out
```

The fields bleed into each other but that is the part that is discarded anyway by the recombination:

Conditional select

```
BCD_EFG_HI0
110_110_110
00A_BCD_EFG
001_001_001
-----------
BCA_EFD_HIG
```

So overall `((x << 1) & 0b110110110) | ((x >> 2) & 0b001001001)`.

Comment: This is definitely a better approach than mine- thanks very much!